# Measuring and splitting up coastline

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm currently starting a project about beach cleaning and preservation.
Is there a way of getting the coastline layer from OSM for a country as a whole length of vectors and use some algorithms to split it into more manageable bits of approx. 1m sections that can be referenced by unique identifier? For example to set status of work, eg. been cleaned or yet to be. With some more tags and photos for the groups of volunteers to log and document the progress.

Thanks a bunch in advance, I'm still just on the first steps of getting to know the concept of OSM and openlayers

Answer (score 0):

Getting the data is the first step, there are many possible ways to achieve this.
If you are only looking for the coast lines, no matter the country, this seems promising:
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-coastline/
Otherwise, you can derive the coastlines from country data (again, many sources available, OSM is only one of them)

Once you have your coast lines, all you need to do is go over all the coordinates and create new features once the desired length is reached. The unique identifier can either be a simple iterative number (e.g. starting at 1) or a `uuid`, or a combination of country and number (somalia_142). There is no magic algorithm needed, just measure the length of each segment (between 2 coordinates) with [getDistance](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getDistance)

But most likely you want to pre-process your data in a desktop-GIS like QGIS and then build your application with that data. Creating a database with pictures and other information is another story.